# VueJS and Firestore: Updating a document property happens twice

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2, vuex

**I got a click handler that, when clicked, for some reason is updating my value twice (incrementing or decrementing twice).** It doesn't happen all the time, but I would say 90% of the time. I want to prevent that and only update the value once.

Let me explain.

First, here's my button template code:

```
          <b-button
            variant="link"
            class="mb-2"
            @click="clueHandler(comment)"
          >
```

Here is the script code for the `clueHandler`:

```
async clueHandler(comment) {
  const inClues =
    this.clues.findIndex((clue) => clue.id === comment.id) > -1
  if (this.loggedIn) {
    if (inClues) {
      await this.$store.dispatch('removeCommentFromCluesFeed', comment)
      console.log('dispatched from clueHandler')
    } else if (!inClues) {
      await this.$store.dispatch('addCommentToCluesFeed', comment)
      console.log('dispatched from clueHandler')
    }
  } else {
    this.$router.replace('/login')
  }
},
```

Here's the logic in Vuex for updating the Firestore document property:

```
  async addCommentToCluesFeed({ state }, comment) {
    try {
      const cluesFeedDoc = this.$fireStore
        .collection(`users/${state.userProfile.uid}/clues`)
        .doc(comment.id)
      await cluesFeedDoc.set(comment)
      console.log('clue added from addCommentToCluesFeed action')
      await this.$fireStore
        .collection('comments')
        .doc(comment.id)
        .update({
          clueVotes: parseInt(comment.clueVotes) + 1 // <<<<------------HERE !!
        })
      console.log('clue vote increased from addCommentToCluesFeed action')
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        'error adding clue from addCommentToCluesFeed action',
        error
      )
    }
  },
```

Here's a screenshot of the area the handler is updating:

[image]

What happens is that when you click ONCE on the template button with the clueHandler, the document property `clueVotes` is incremented twice (or decremented twice depending on whether the clue was already set by the user previously).

Here is an example of what the database shows when a user clicks the button for the first time:

[image]
It should only be `clueVotes: 1`.

Anyone have any advice or thoughts on what is happening or how I can fix? I am assuming this is going to be related to not fully realizing the promise/race completion, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found an excellent explanation of why I was having this issue. Here it is:
https://fireship.io/snippets/firestore-increment-tips/

Basically, I needed to return a special value that can be used with set() or update() that tells the server to increment the field's current value by the given value.

Here's my code update:

```
            .update({
              clueVotes: this.$fireStoreObj.FieldValue.increment(1)
            })
```